# Error when converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: c#

I have little error when converting numeric to data type numeric. 
i need to take hours(decimal) between 2 date (dateTime).

but I see error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Arithmetic overflow error
>   converting numeric to data type numeric.

```
var hours = (dateTime1 - dateTime2).TotalHours;
res = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(hours),2);
```

how can i clean take hours?

Comment: what is value of hours?

Comment: We need more info, you're getting an SQL exception, but we can't see how you get your datetimes.

Comment: date I enter by hands from the win.form ```NEW_DateTime1 (DateTime) = 11.06.2019 09:55:00
NEW_DateTime2 (DateTime) = 27.06.2019 09:52:00 and res in db decimal(4,3)```

Comment: You are getting an SQL exception but there is no DB access in the code provided. Include the code where the actual exception is coming from.

Comment: Perhaps depending on the database. But a decimal(4,3) specifies a max length of 4 and reserves 3 digits for precision. So if res is 10.0, you'll get an error. Meaning the highest value you can save would be 9.999.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't convert TotalHours to decimal, it is a **double**, just leave that as is
2. Ensure that the column in the SQL table you are writing this to is of type **float**